# Public blog site settings in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I set up a public blog site with Sharepoint and completed all anonymous access settings. I gave Add, Edit, Delete, View permissions to anonymous users for the Comments list as described [here](http://www.alpesh.nakars.com/blog/howto-set-permissions-for-comments-on-sharepoint-blog/)

The problem is, on the home page when an anonymous user clicks on the title of a post, browser asks for login information. The requested page is "http://blogsite/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1"

Anonymous comments are enabled but users won't be able to add comments unless they can access the post details page.

Any help?

Comment: And I tried adding a location element to web config for the url above to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to provide Read access to the blog itself. (The Posts list) and Limited Access to the rest of the site so users can navigate to the posts.